# self study- question on Hierarchical binomial model

Tags: self-study, bayesian

I am trying to solve exercise 5.13 in Gelman et. al. Bayesian Data Analysis (third edition).
The exercise says:

Hierarchical binomial model: Exercise 3.8 described a survey of bicycle traffic in Berkeley,
California, with data displayed in Table 3.3. For this problem, restrict your attention to
the first two rows of the table: residential streets labeled as ‘bike routes,’ which we will
use to illustrate this computational exercise.

The data are  `y=[16  9 10 13 19 20 18 17 35 55]` and `n=[ 74  99  58  70 122  77 104 129 308 119]`.

> (a) Set up a hierarchical model for the observed number of bicycles on streets
>   $ j =1, \cdots , 10$ that is binomial with unknown probability $\theta_j$ and sample size equal to
>   the total number of vehicles (bicycles included) in that block. Assign a beta
>   population distribution for the parameter $\theta_j$ and a non-informative hyperprior
>   distribution. Write down the joint posterior distribution.
>
> (b) Compute the marginal posterior density of the hyperparameters and draw simulations from the joint posterior distribution of the parameters and hyperparameters.
>
> (c) Compare the posterior distributions of the parameters $\theta_j$ to the raw proportions in location j.
>
> (d) Give a 95% CI for the average underlying proportion of traffic that is bicycles.
>
> (e) A location on a new residential street with a bicycle route is sampled at random during which time 100 vehicles of all kinds go by. Give a 95% CI for the Number of those vehicles that are bicycles. Discuss how much you trust this
>   interval in application.

I have managed to solve (a), (b) and (c). I would like to ask if you could help me with (d) and (e). 
For question (d) I thought to do the following: For each variable $\theta_j$ I have computed the 95% CI. So the mean of these lower(upper) bounds will be the lower(upper) bound for the wanted CI. Is this correct?

For question (e) I thought the following: Let [a,b] be the 95%CI from (d) question.  The meaning of this CI is (correct me please if I am wrong) :[a,b] is the  interval where with 95% probability the observed vehicle is bicycle. So, from the 100 new observed vehicles I predict that 95 of them will lie among a and b will be bicycle. But, I don't understant if I can trust this interval.  Could you please give me a hint.

Please, I don't want you to solve the excercise for me, just give me hints to continue.

Answer (score 1):

(d) You should have many samples from the posterior distribution of $\{\theta_j\}$ for $j=1,\cdots,10$ **and also** $\alpha$ and $\beta$ the parameters of a Beta distribution from which the $\theta_j$ were drawn. What you want is the 95% confidence interval for the expected value of these beta distributions. The expected value of a beta distribution with parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is $\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}$. Thus, what you need to do is calculate $\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}$ for each of your posterior samples, and then take your 95% confidence intervals from the distribution of these vales.

(e) Given each of the beta distributions discussed in part (d), you can sample it to get a new value $\theta$ for an unknown new street. You can then generate a binomial variable with this $\theta$ and $N=100$. This wil give you a sample from the posterior predictive distribution for a new measurement in a street with 100 vehicles. Again, the distribution of all these samples is what you are interested in. Use this to create a 95% CI.